# Cookies path with Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring, cookies, spring-cloud, jsessionid, spring-cloud-gateway

Consider this **microservices** based application using *Spring Boot 2.1.2* and *Spring Cloud Greenwich.RELEASE*:

- Each microservice uses the **JSESSIONID cookie** to identify its own **dedicated Servlet session** (i.e. no global unique session shared with Spring Session and Redis).
- External incoming requests are routed by **Spring Cloud Gateway** (and an Eureka registry used through Spring Cloud Netflix, but this should not be relevant).

When Spring Cloud Gateway returns a microservice response, it returns the "Set-Cookie" as-is, i.e. with the same "/" path.

When a second microservice is called by a client, the JSESSIONID from the first microservice is forwarded but ignored (since the corresponding session only exists in the first microservice). So the second microservice will return a new JSESSIONID. As a consequence the first session is lost.

In summary, **each call to a different microservice will loose the previous session**.

I expected some cookies path translation with Spring Cloud Gateway, but found no such feature in the docs. Not luck either with Google.

How can we fix this (a configuration parameter I could have missed, an
API to write such cookies path translation, etc)?

Comment: There is no stickey session support. I think you can rewrite headers which is all a cookie is.

Comment: Yes GlobalFilter seems to be of help here.

Comment: unfortunately, jsessionid is double-used by the infrastructure and overwritten in a PCF environment. we solved the stickyness session problem you are describing with rewrite cookie name in headers as spencergibb said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than changing the JSESSIONID cookies path in a GlobalFilter, I simply changed the name of the cookie in the `application.yml`:

```
# Each microservice uses its own session cookie name to prevent conflicts
server.servlet.session.cookie.name: JSESSIONID_${spring.application.name}
```

Comment: In if you are in the Webflux world, you can accomplish the same thing with this: `server.reactive.session.cookie.name: SESSIONID_${spring.application.name}`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found the following solution using *Spring Boot* 2.5.4 and *Spring Cloud Gateway* 2020.0.3:

To be independent from the Cookie naming of the downstream services, I decided to rename all cookies on the way through the gateway. But to avoid a duplicate session cookie in downstream requests (from the gateway itself) I also renamed the gateway cookie.

## Rename the Gateway Session Cookie

Unfortunately [customizing the gateway cookie name](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/27833) using `server.servlet.session.cookie.name` does not work using current gateway versions.

Therefore register a custom `WebSessionManager` bean (name required as the auto configurations is conditional on the bean name!) changing the cookie name (use whatever you like except typical session cookie names like `SESSION`, `JSESSION_ID`, …):

```
static final String SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = "GATEWAY_SESSION";

@Bean(name = WebHttpHandlerBuilder.WEB_SESSION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME)
WebSessionManager webSessionManager(WebFluxProperties webFluxProperties) {
    DefaultWebSessionManager webSessionManager = new DefaultWebSessionManager();
    CookieWebSessionIdResolver webSessionIdResolver = new CookieWebSessionIdResolver();
    webSessionIdResolver.setCookieName(SESSION_COOKIE_NAME);
    webSessionIdResolver.addCookieInitializer((cookie) -> cookie
            .sameSite(webFluxProperties.getSession().getCookie().getSameSite().attribute()));
    webSessionManager.setSessionIdResolver(webSessionIdResolver);
    return webSessionManager;
}
```

## Rename Cookies created

Next step is to rename (all) cookies set by the downstream server. This is easy as there is a `RewriteResponseHeader` filter available. I decided to simply add a prefix to every cookie name (choose a unique one for each downstream):

```
filters:
  - "RewriteResponseHeader=Set-Cookie, ^([^=]+)=, DS1_$1="
```

## Rename Cookies sent

Last step is to rename the cookies before sending to the downstream server. As every cookie of the downstream server has a unique prefix, just remove the prefix:

```
filters:
  - "RewriteRequestHeader=Cookie, ^DS1_([^=]+)=, $1="
```

Arg, [currently there is no such filter available](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/2353). But based on the existing `RewriteResponseHeader` filter this is easy (the Cloud Gateway will use it if you register it as a bean):

```
@Component
class RewriteRequestHeaderGatewayFilterFactory extends RewriteResponseHeaderGatewayFilterFactory
{
    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return new GatewayFilter() {
            @Override
            public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
                ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest().mutate()
                        .headers(httpHeaders -> rewriteHeaders(httpHeaders, config)).build();
                return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return filterToStringCreator(RewriteRequestHeaderGatewayFilterFactory.this)
                        .append("name", config.getName()).append("regexp", config.getRegexp())
                        .append("replacement", config.getReplacement()).toString();
            }
        };
    }

    private void rewriteHeaders(HttpHeaders httpHeaders, Config config)
    {
        httpHeaders.put(config.getName(), rewriteHeaders(config, httpHeaders.get(config.getName())));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply reset cookie name to GATEWAY_SESSION in gateway project to avoid session conflict:

```
    @Autowired(required = false)
    public void setCookieName(HttpHandler httpHandler) {
        if (httpHandler == null) return;
        if (!(httpHandler instanceof HttpWebHandlerAdapter)) return;
        DefaultWebSessionManager sessionManager = new DefaultWebSessionManager();
        CookieWebSessionIdResolver sessionIdResolver = new CookieWebSessionIdResolver();
        sessionIdResolver.setCookieName("GATEWAY_SESSION");
        sessionManager.setSessionIdResolver(sessionIdResolver);
        ((HttpWebHandlerAdapter) httpHandler).setSessionManager(sessionManager);
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not help differentiate the cookies of the various microservices.

Comment: @FlorianBeaufumé Yes, No need to distinguish in my case, Can you tell me your scene,The same browser client needs to log in to multiple microservices?

Comment: Yes, in my case the browser needs to use a session for each microservice.