# How to configure Spring Cloud Gateway to use sessions with Redis?

Tags: java, spring, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

Currently I have to login for each request I make through the api gateway. The session's keys are being persisted on Redis and if I make requests directly to my microservices without using the gateway it works as expected, (I login once and can make requests to any microservice). I think the problem is the SESSION cookie is being deleted for every request I make through the gateway but I don't know how to configure this to stop happening

I added these dependencies to every microservice including the api gateway:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

this is the gateway application.properties:

```
spring.application.name = api-gateway
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
server.port=9191
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=SERVICE1
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=http://localhost:8081/service1
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/service1
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=SERVICE2
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=http://localhost:8082/service2
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/service2
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
spring.session.store-type=redis
spring.cloud.gateway.default-filters=SaveSession
server.servlet.session.timeout= 1800s
```

Comment: maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55869694/cookies-path-with-spring-cloud-gateway